# How to add a third tab bar item that points to a uitabelviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2, tabbar

How do I add a third tab bar item to a tab bar and have it point to a UITabelViewController?

I started out with a TabBar project template that comes packaged with Xcode 4.2.  It comes pre-configured with two tabs which I have used,however, I would like to add a third tab and have it point to a UITabelViewController.  I tried dragging a "Tab Bar Item" from the Objects window into the tab bar, but it did not allow me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dragging `Tab Bar Item` drag the `Table View Controller` to the tab bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Object Navigator in Interface builder, expand the tabBar and just copy one item under that and paste it there. it will create another tabItem and if you expand it you will be able to change the UIViewController in it to UITableViewController